# Container controllers and iOS 6 rotations

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, ios6

My app supports portrait, landscape left and lansdscape right orientation, but in some places of the app I only support portrait.

Making the iOS 6 adaptation I have a problem. I show a modal controller inside a UINavigationController, and the root controller has the rotation methods implemented but never being called because new rotation behaviors with controllers that are inside of a container one.

My question has a quick response: if I have a controller which does not support all app orientations, and that controller is inside a container controller, do I have to subclass that container (in my case the navigation) to override rotation methods and accomplish my target?

I think that is very tricky but I don't find another solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several "pseudo official" source that subclassing a container class, specifically the UINavigationController is the way to go to achieve orientation task.

Here are some links to Apple developers forum with corporate answers stating this:

- https://devforums.apple.com/message/740014#740014
- https://devforums.apple.com/message/744384#744384

The category method used by many developers is not correct, see **thread#message 728805#728805**
(can't post more than two links)

Answer (score 0):

Yea. Subclass your UINavigationController and override the autorotation methods for portrait.

Comment: Why? Is there any point in the documentation that says that I have to do that?

Comment: I didn't find this method in any documentation. I just thought of it on my own. It works so good enough for me.